# Create a custom tag name for a GitLab release via a Pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm learning how to create releases with GitLab pipelines. GitLab *recommends* you use semantic versioning. However, I would like to create a release with a custom tag name. Specifically, I would like to include:

- Month
- Day of Month
- Build number of the day

The final bullet is what is tripping me up. Is there a way in GitLab to include the build number of the day? Azure DevOps has a revision number variable. However, I don't see anything similar in GitLab. As I'm learning, I'm concerned I'm missing something. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GitLab, the rough equivalent for [ADO's `$Build.BuildNumber`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) would be `$CI_PIPELINE_IID`. The `$CI_PIPELINE_IID` starts at 1 for the first pipeline and increments by one for every pipeline.

If you want a unique ID for each *job* (rather than pipeline) then `$CI_JOB_ID` is the closest thing. It will always go up, but it won't necessarily be sequential.